# SeekBar at the top of the layout in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, layout, seekbar

I would like to reproduce the SeekBar position of Google Music application but I can’t find a way to do it. I’ve tried padding and margin without success.

Here is what I’d like to reproduce:

[image]

And here is my actual layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/music_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="#BBBBBB">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/musicSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/played" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/playPauseButton"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play_pause"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/musicSeekBar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/played"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/playPauseButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playPauseButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playPauseButton"
            android:text="00:00" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/played"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/played"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="00:00" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seekbar on top of view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658702/seekbar-on-top-of-view)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to overlap the ViewPager with the SeekBar. The easiest way to accomplish that is by having the ViewPager and the SeekBar in the same RelativeLayout, with the SeekBar having a negative `android:layout_marginTop`.

In your layout, it's probably easiest to replace LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout with three children: the ViewPager, the nested RelativeLayout and the Seekbar.

Comment: Thank you for the tips but I ve fixed it alone using a view with going under the seekbar having the same color as the page

Comment: @user3119384 Can you please share the code . Need to do the same.