# Seekbar on top of view

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am trying to implement a seekbar on top of a view like in Google Play Music app. I couldn't find answer for this anywhere.I tried negative marginBottom but the thumb was getting cut off. I found a similar post on SO [SeekBar at the top of the layout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952966/seekbar-at-the-top-of-the-layout-in-android) but with no answer so had to post this. Please help. Reference image from Google play music below.

[image: Reference image]

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/album_art_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


       <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark"
        android:thumb= "@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
        />

    <!--<View
    <!--    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     <!--   android:layout_height="1dp"
    <!--    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    <!--    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     <!--   />   // Commenting this as this is not bottom view in my case

</FrameLayout>
```

Bottom View :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/player_footer_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_pager">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/audio_player_btn_play_dimensions"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/audio_player_btn_play_dimensions"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/play"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/audio_player_btn_play_dimensions"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/audio_player_btn_play_dimensions"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_white"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/audio_player_btn_play_dimensions"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/audio_player_btn_play_dimensions"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_prev_white"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnNext"
         android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've quickly knocked up a layout to give you an idea how to do it. I've used a simple `View` with a background colour at the top and at the bottom of the layout so you can clearly see it works, and the `SeekBar` overlaps them both.  You can then replace the `View` at the top with your `ViewPager` and the one at the bottom with whatever you want at the bottom of the screen. Note that the `layout_height` on the inner `FrameLayout` is double the negative `layout_marginBottom`. These values don't matter too much as long as they are big enough to fit your contents and the negative margin is half your `layout_height` (e.g. you could just as well set `layout_height="50dp"` and `layout_marginBottom="-25dp". on the` FrameLayout` and it will still look right, although you don't want them much bigger than necessary as that would create unnecessary overdrawing of the overlapping views).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/album_art_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomView"
        android:background="#f00"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#00f"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/album_art_viewpager"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/songProgressBar1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a screenshot to show you how it looks:
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Your answer is a perfect example. But in my case, my bottom view height is set to match parent and view pager height I am drawing it from onMeasure. In that case, seekbar is overlapping the bottom view. Added bottom view in the code.

Comment: @RisingUp I'm sorry but I don't really understand how the bottom view layout you've now added to the question fits with the first layout XML you have in the question. Is the bottom view added inside the `FrameLayout` from the first layout, or are they in some other higher level `ViewGroup`? Is there any reason you can't represent it in a single XML file as that would make it easier to understand. Alternatively seeing the code where you add the bottom view might be helpful to see how the two layouts fit together.

Comment: On top I have FrameLayout which has a Viewpager and seekbar . And below that I have the bottom view which I added . So , my question is to merge the FrameLayout view & Bottom view in a way that Seekbar should appear as I asked in question. I kept bottom view separate only to avoid confusion for future readers. Actually both FrameLayout view and Bottom view are part of same XML.